# how to create 2 java web services (wars) in a single web application in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7

Please help me in creating a single java web application in netbeans 7 that consists of two java web services (wars). For example one service is web services that serves front end user directly by communicating with another service like database services. Two services should be deployable with a single build.xml so that front end developer or client feels as if there is only one services.

Comment: Please tell us what your current ideas are. Have you actually spend more than 10 minutes thinking about how to do this?

Comment: I wish to implement two web services one for database services and another for web services this is working fine as a single build in eclipse with ant script. But the same when shifted to netbeans its either not supporting or not able to configure two apps in to a single build @Izmaki